# Which is better for a token to store - SESSION or Cookie, for CSRF prevention?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on the security issues for my web application. And i have to deal with the CSRF.  Gone through many refrences but some of them uses **Cookie** while other uses **SESSION** .

Comment: Sessions also use cookies. And should really try to expand that question a bit, state some more context and actual concerns/questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CSRF prevention you need to store a shared token on both the client **and** the server, so when the client makes a request, their submitted value can be compared with your known value.

For the *client* side you could use a *cookie*, or a hidden form field (personally I prefer the hidden field - so I don't pile up cookies for every form in the clients browser).

On the *server* you could use the *session* (where the session id is stored in a cookie anyway) or store it in a database (although you'd probably need to use the session to identify the record that belongs to the client).

Here's some very basic example CSRF prevention code for you.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['csrf'])) {
    var_dump($_POST, $_SESSION);
    if ($_POST['csrf'] == $_SESSION['CSRF_FORM1']) {
        print 'You win cookies!';
    }
    else {
        print 'You win a bucket of vomit!';
    }
}

$_SESSION['CSRF_FORM1'] = md5(microtime());

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php print $_SESSION['CSRF_FORM1']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Good form Jack!" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="badValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Bad form Jack!" />
</form>
```